# How do I use lightDOM <content> inside Polymer's dom-repeat

Tags: polymer, web-component

In Polymer 1.2, How do I use content in dom-repeat?.

```
//component
<dom-module id="data-stream">
     <template>
           ...
           <div class="data-stream-list">
                <template is="dom-repeat" items="[[stream]]">
                    <div class="data-stream-item">
                          <content></content>
                      </div>
                </template>
            </div>
     </template>
      ...
</dom-module>


//used as
<data-stream>
   <!--// template for data stream item -->
   <div class="custom-data-stream-item">[[item]]</div>
</data-stream>
```

Supposing i had a hypothetical stream of [one, two, three, four] this returns

```
...
<div class="data-stream-list">
        <div class="data-stream-item">
              <div class="custom-data-stream-item"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="data-stream-item"></div>
        <div class="data-stream-item"></div>
        <div class="data-stream-item"></div>
</div>
...
```

Implying the light DOM is stamped at least once but not repeated. Neither does there seem to be any binding. Not as expected.

Answer (score 1):

That is just not supported. If you have several `<content>` elements without a selector, all children will be projected to the first `<content>` element.

If you add a `select="someSelector"` where `someSelector` is different for each `<content>` element and matches with a child each then it might work (not sure if dynamically added `<content>` elements are supported at all).